# Moving website to Django with existing PostgreSQL DB

Tags: django, postgresql

I am moving my web application from rails to django, I have successfully connected to my PostgreSQL DB with the django application. My question is, do I have to recreate all of the rails models in django (which will create new database tables) or is there a way to use the existing tables as they are? I am looking through documentation but have not found the specific answer I am looking for.

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/2.2/howto/legacy-databases/

Answer (score 1):

You can say to django that you don't want your table to be created by adding a *managed* attribute to *False* on your models Meta.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        managed = False
```

The classes for the models can be created with the *inspectdb* management command.
This command will set the *managed* attribute to False.

I suggest that you create this model file, remove the *managed* attribute, et create an initial migrations. You will then manually insert the row for this initial migration on your production database (*django_migrations* table if I remember correctly) to tell Django that all those tables have already been created.

Comment: Do you recommend doing things in the order you provided? If I remove the managed attribute and run initial migrations before I manually enter the row into django_migrations, will it try to create the tables again?

Comment: It should try to create the tables, but I think it would fail since they already exists. I would generate the models, remove the managed attribute, and create the initial migration. Then, before pushing to production, I would add the initial migration to the DB.